# Dynamically update android ui for an animation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview

I have implemented a layout update animation by referring [this article](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/layout.html). It is working fine when I click a button ui gets updated. Now I want to automate this process. That means automatically update the ui. I have used handler within a for loop to update the ui periodically like follows

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                final ViewGroup newView = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(
                        R.layout.list_item, containerGroup, false);
                TextView tv = (TextView) newView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                tv.setText(RAVEMSGS[(int) (Math.random()*RAVEMSGS.length)]);
                containerGroup.addView(newView,0);

            }
        },2000);
    }
```

but this is not working. How can I update the ui dynamically for the animation ?

Note : I posted only a part of the code which I have used to update the list view this piece of code is working if I call it withing a onclick listner of a button.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to update Ui from runOnUiThread........

```
try {
                 // code runs in a thread
                 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // your code for animation
                        }
                 });
           } catch (final Exception ex) {
               Log.i("---","Exception in thread");
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

did you write this code in a thread? try this:

```
        // main thread
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        new Thread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){

                    handler.post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            final ViewGroup newView = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(
                                    R.layout.list_item, containerGroup, false);
                            TextView tv = (TextView) newView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                            tv.setText(RAVEMSGS[(int) (Math.random()*RAVEMSGS.length)]);
                            containerGroup.addView(newView,0);

                        }
                    });

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

        }).start();
```